# How to create odbc connection string for accessing a remote database?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, odbc

I have to connect to a remote database using odbc connection. They provided me IPaddress,database name,ServerPort number,user name and password. With this I have done like this,

```
 <?php
  $ipaddress='*****';
 $database='aaa';
 $user='ased';, 
 $pass='EEEE';
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Adaptive Server Anywhere 12.0  Driver};Server=$ipaddress;Database=$database; ",$user, $pass);
   if(!$conn)
   {
echo "Connection not found";
   }
 else 
 {
  echo "Database exists";
  }
```

but it shows an error

```
  Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you have not configured php to access Oracle DB. Please try setting `php.ini` to enable `odbc` as follows:

1. ;extension=php_oci8.dll (remove ';' from begining to enable)
2. ;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll (remove ';' from begining to enable)
3. ;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll  (remove ';' from begining to enable)

After enabling the above settings just try out with a local Oracle DB if available/possible to verify compatability... If it works, its most likely to work for remote ODB too with correct credentials.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I meant about connecting MS sql using ODBC connection

Comment: In that case visit: "http://in2.php.net/mssql". Official PHP Manual for MS SQL connectivity...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are having trouble because the function `odbc_connect` is not found at runtime. I don't know how PHP is configured at your end but I suggest you run `phpinfo()` to see if odbc support is enabled in your PHP.

And you can run the following to know if `odbc` extension is loaded at runtime.

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

And finally you can check if `odbc_connect` is defined at runtime by using following line.

```
print_r(get_defined_functions());
```

Hope this helps to pinpoint the problem you are having. And this may lead to an appropriate solution. Please share the outputs of the above if you are still having trouble.

Always happy to help..

Comment: thankyou for the response.I have tried with print_r(get_defined_functions()); it doesnt contain any terms relating to odbc

Comment: Then the odbc extension is not being loaded at all. So, you need to enable that extension first. The process may vary depending on the OS and PHP configuration you currently have.